# Retrieve inner HTML of AngularJS directive before templateUrl overrides it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive I use for form validation boilerplate which I recently refactored. Allow me to explain the directive a little further before expanding.

The directive usage:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="personalDetails" validated-form>

    <!-- Pass buttons into form through here -->
    <a href="" class="btn btn-success" 
        data-ng-click="saveDetails()"
        data-ng-disabled="!personalDetails.$valid">Save Changes</a>

</form>
```

Previously, my directive looked something like this, and it **worked**.

```
app.directive('validatedForm', function($compile, $sce) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            var template = //... HTML boilerplate code
            var buttons  = element.html(); // Get contents of element before overriding

            element.html(template + buttons);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);

        }
    }
});
```

The html template was becoming messy, and I wanted to wrap the buttons 'inside' of the template, rather than after them. So I refactored into what I thought was a much better directive.

```
app.directive('validatedForm', ['$compile', '$sce', function ($compile, $sce) {

    var domContent = null;

    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: '/Content/ngViews/directives/validated-form.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            // This now returns the contents of templateUrl 
            // instead of what the directive had as inner HTML
            domContent = element.html(); 

            // Scope
            scope.form = {
                caption: attrs.caption,
                location: 'Content/ngViews/forms/' + attrs.name + '.html',
                buttons: $sce.trustAsHtml(domContent),
                showButtons: !(domContent.replace(' ', '') === '')
            };

        }
    };
}]);
```

So what I'm noticing is that element.html() now retrieves the contents of the templateUrl instead of the contents of the inner HTML of my directive. How else can I get the contents of my directive before it gets overriden by the templateUrl?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To access the iniital html can use `$transclude` within directive controller. This is a slight change from earlier versions so assumes using 1.2

```
controller:function($scope,$transclude){
      $transclude(function(clone,scope){
        /* for demo am converting to html string*/
         $scope.buttons=angular.element('<div>').append(clone).html();
      });

    }
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/tArVj75kcE6atfjyhnK3?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: This does exactly what you say and is the right answer, though as a follow up - binding the passed HTML into the templateUrl via ng-bind-html using $sce.trustAsHtml() is messing up the click events which are passed with the scope. Is this due to the presence of a new controller in the directive?

Comment: not sure whay you use that to be honest... simply passing the html in from scope won't get it compiled. Create demo. Overall am a bit confused about what you are doing....just gave you a way to access the html as requested. You can use plunker to import the templateURL...just create a file with the html in it and adjust url to same directory ( just file)

Comment: Thanks, will hack away at it a bit longer. And will post an update if I find out what the issue is. Probably something to do with my code. Like I said, this is the right answer to the actual question regardless, thanks!

Comment: how can this work? `$transclude` can't seem to be injected into the controller.

Comment: @EliranMalka You must add a `transclude: true` in directive's return func (where the `link` func usually is)