# AngularJS directives with children

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to make a directive that could be used like this:

```
<my-directive>
    <name>Blah</name>
    <age>20</age>
    <address>
        ...
    </address>
</my-directive>
```

My expectation was that I would be able to access the child elements in the link function and get their inner HTMLs. However, that does not work as you don't get the "previous" HTML. I followed the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110927/retrieve-inner-html-of-angularjs-directive-before-templateurl-overrides-it) and that gives me the previous HTML, but `clone` is "raw HTML". It's an array of HTML objects, and I can't really search it or anything.

Is there anyway to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use in directive

```
transclude:true
```

And for
children drective

```
require: '^parent',
```

For example click [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/72PjQSOlckGyUQnH7zOA?p=preview)

Comment: Ok, this doesn't actually let me access the child from the parent (something like accessing the inner html of `name` from `my-directive`).

Comment: You can get access the parent from child

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to call children function on your element.

```
var children = element.children();
```